# How do I restrict templates to specific types?

Tags: c++

For simplicity, say I usually want to pass in strings and basic data types in here:

```
template <typename T>
void writeLine(const T &ob)
{
    std::cout << ob << std::endl;
}
```

In most cases, I would pass std::string, int, char, float, etc. But say that I don't want it to accept floats. In real world scenarios, I may not want it to accept certain classes.

Is there a way to restrict what the template type accepts?

Comment: Look at [static assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [std::is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)......that may lead you in the correct direction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can, the most simple way for your example is to put a `static_assert` in your function.

```
template <typename T>
void writeLine(const T &ob)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T, float>::value, "You can't use floats here");
    std::cout << ob << std::endl;
}
```

This will give you a compile time error if you try and use the function with a float.

Another option is called [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and is used to make the template parameter deduction fail under certain circumstances.

Usually you use [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in combination with some templates from `<type_traits>` header. The same thing with SFINAE would look something like:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, float>::value, int>::type = 0>
void writeLine(const T &ob)
{
    std::cout << ob << std::endl;
}
```

Let's break down `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, float>::value, int>::type`.

`!std::is_same<T, float>::value` is the condition here, if this condition is true this template will have a `::type`, otherwise it will not.

After the condition we can specify what we want the type to be if the condition is true, in this case we use `int`. If this is not specified it will default to `void`.

So as long as we don't pass a float to this template, the second template parameter will be deduced to `int = 0`. If we pass in a float the deduction will simply fail and you will get a `no matching function` error showing the template as a candidate with failed deduction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm not sure if the first example is buggy. I passed in a float and it compiled. If I pass in an integer, it says "You can't use floats here." It seems to work if I negate is_same.

Comment: I missed putting a `!` at the beginning. Fixed now.

Comment: "After the condition we can specify what we want the type to be if the condition is true", why did you chose `int`? Also, "the second template parameter will be deduced to int = 0", what's the significance of `int = 0`?

Comment: @425nesp Using a non-type parameter makes it impossible to explicitly specify it, which is a good thing. But what type is used is not important. `int` is a good choice since it's easy to give it a default value. `int = 0` is needed since if we don't give it a default value, it will fail to deduce.